# get user id when created a new posts

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i wanted to retrieve id from Users Table for user_id field in Posts table

i've already tried with Auth::id(); but its retrieving current authenticated Id

so what i wanted is, when i created new data, the id from Users to be displayed at user_id Field in Posts Table

This is my Post model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

This is my User Model:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(post::class);
}
```

and this is how i currently stored my data:

```
$post = new post;
    // $post->parent_id = $request->input('id');
    $post->user_id = Auth::id(); 
    $post->type = $request->input('type');
    $post->slug = str_slug($request->input('title'));
    $post->title = $request->input('title');
    $post->body = $request->input('body');
    $post->excerpt = $request->input('excerpt');
    $post->image = $imageName;
    $post->tag = $request->input('tag');
    $post->metas = $request->input('metas');
    $post->ispublished = $request->input('ispublished');
    $post->published_at = $request->input('published_at');
    $post->save();
```

how do i exactly do what i want?

// edited
i'm new to this so i got my questions all wrong,

i already got what i want by using Auth::id.
i just wanted to record the id of the creator of the posts

Comment: just to be clear.. you want to create a new post on behalf of another user? not the user whos is currently authenticated ?

Comment: Auth::id() always return the id of current logged in user. what is the issue... please reply for @MekjkrhG comments.

Comment: is it correct using Auth::id() ? or there is another way to retrieve id from usersTable?

Comment: Using `Auth::id()` is fine... you can also use it like `Auth::user()->id`  and it's id from users table.

Comment: it depends on what you are trying to do. Example User Dave is logged in and he is creating a post. if you want this post to be under User Dave than Auth::id() is correct. but if you want this Post to be under User Bob than you have to pass Bobs ID with the form.

Comment: okay @MekjkrhG i think this clear my question, pardon my english please :D

Comment: thanks for @VikashPathak for anwering too

Comment: awesome glad i was able to help

Answer (score 0):

your question isn't clear exactly, but you can use relationship to this work like :

```
$user->post()->create([
    $post->type = $request->input('type');
    $post->slug = str_slug($request->input('title'));
    $post->title = $request->input('title');
    $post->body = $request->input('body');
    $post->excerpt = $request->input('excerpt');
    $post->image = $imageName;
    $post->tag = $request->input('tag');
    $post->metas = $request->input('metas');
    $post->ispublished = $request->input('ispublished');
    $post->published_at = $request->input('published_at');
]);
```

This solution isn't really good in terms of performance because it uses join.

Answer (score 0):

Check your routes to the controller if it has middleware. To retrieve user data through Auth middleware is required.

**Example**

```
Route::post('/', 'PostController@store')->middleware('auth:users');
```